# How do Meteor Android / iOS apps work?

Tags: android, ios, meteor

Everywhere on the Internet I see that you run some command and you have a android/ios app.

How would that app work?

Does it communicate with the meteor server? If I put the meteor app online and someone create an account on website could login with that account in the app?

If when I run the command to create the apk, the database has 10 000 items in 2 collections, all that database will be in the apk ? What if the android user open the app and he isn't connected to the Internet?

Comment: Try this https://www.meteor.com/tutorials/blaze/running-on-mobile

Comment: I have the same doubt. did you get any answer ? I mean how does meteor android/ios app communicate with native api ? cordova ?

Comment: I think I my doubt is correct. https://github.com/meteor/meteor/wiki/Meteor-Cordova-Phonegap-integration

Comment: @agpt look [Cordova](https://cordova.apache.org/) based then?